# Не работает авторизация на сайте Python + requests

Tags: python, requests

Сайт - https://ru0.forgeofempires.com/page/

Код:

```
   import requests
   from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

   url = 'https://ru0.forgeofempires.com/page/'
   url2 = 'https://ru.forgeofempires.com/glps/login_check'
   url3 = 'https://ru14.forgeofempires.com/game/index?'

   headers = {
       'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.11; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0'
   }

   datas = {
       'login[userid]': '', #Логин
       'login[password]': '', #Пароль
   }



   with requests.Session() as session:
       session.get(url, headers=headers)
       session.headers.update(headers)


       session.post(url2, data=datas)
       end = session.get(url)
```

Пожалуста, помогите, а то я уже 5 день втыкаю в это(

Comment: session.post(url2, headers =datas) попробуйте так